# C# compiler compiles .txt .obj .java files

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

```
using System;
class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I save the file as `1.java`, `2.obj` and `3.txt`.
I then use the Visual Studio Command Prompt to compile the file: `csc 1.java csc 2.obj csc 3.txt`

Surprisingly, it compiles all the 3 files into an executable and executes it successfully.

Could anyone give me an explanation on this behavior?

Comment: File extensions mean nothing to the background processes.

Comment: Note that in visual studio you can select a file in the solution explorer and choose what happens to it regarding compiling, marking a a resource, copying to output etc. This is used extensively in [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) projects.

Comment: It's not surprising: it's a valid C# program. 

The compiler follows the "Do not judge a book by its cover" rule. The "compiler does not judge a file by its extension", or name. It checks its content and generates the exe file.

Now it would be surprising if the contents of the file WERE NOT valid C# statements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Beginning C# Objects: From Concepts to Code - By Jacquie Barker, Grant Palmer](http://books.google.com.pk/books?id=id86cAxxffcC&pg=PA425&lpg=PA425&dq=The%20recommended%20convention%20is%20to%20end%20source%20code%20file%20names%20with%20the%20extension%20.cs,%20but%20there%20is%20no%20requirement%20to%20do%20so&source=bl&ots=YAw-OMko6J&sig=Xu2inSY76cnSwaZugZK_Xmg46E4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Rr3GUJ_EE4HU0QWun4DgDA&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=The%20recommended%20convention%20is%20to%20end%20source%20code%20file%20names%20with%20the%20extension%20.cs,%20but%20there%20is%20no%20requirement%20to%20do%20so&f=false)

> The recommended convention is to end source code file names with the
>   extension .cs, but there is no requirement to do so; a source file
>   could conceivably be named Person.boo, for example

Also from the [same book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=159059360X).

> Similarly, the name of a C# source file doesn't have to match the name
>   of the class or interface defined within that file. For example, the
>   code defining the Professor class could be placed in a file named
>   Blah.cs, but it's considered good practice for a source file name to
>   match the name of the class or interface declared within the file.

Comment: My only comment would be that [there is a language called Boo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boo_(programming_language)), the source-files of which are typically named `[something].boo`, so while it could be named anything, that's a bad example.

Comment: @FakeName, Wow, never knew there is a language called Boo, interesting.. That example was there in the book, (probably the author didn't even know about Boo), and the idea is that the file name + extension can be anything

Answer (score 19):

File extension does not matter to the C# compiler: as long as it gets the text of your program correctly, the compiler does not look at the name or the extension of the file. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for the C# compiler does not mention naming requirements<sup>*</sup>.

Contrast this with Java, where file names and locations are important. Java compiler expects only `*.java` source files, with [file names matching the names of public classes inside them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html):

> Source code file names must have .java suffixes, class file names must have .class suffixes, and both source and class files must have root names that identify the class.

---

<sup>*</sup> Even though the compiler does not require it, `*.cs` remains the commonly accepted naming convention for C# source files.

Comment: @Akina91 That's a little hard, because the [documentation for the C# compoler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd(v=vs.80).aspx) simply does not mention anything that would suggest that there is a naming convention for the source files and their extensions. [Javac docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html), on the other hand, say that "Source code file names must have .java suffixes, class file names must have .class suffixes, and both source and class files must have root names that identify the class."

Comment: `C# source files typically have the file extension .cs`
*Section 1.1, C# language spec 3.0*. No **must** here.