# in .net command line compiler, what happens when random file extension is given in the "out" option?

Tags: c#, file-extension, csc

Example when I compile all cs files to a single assembly(say Single.dll), but When I mention the file extension as random text, as mentioned below

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc -target:library -out:Single.abc *.cs

It is not throwing error, but creates a file as "Single.abc"

what is the purpose of doing this kind of compilation?

See example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe

Comment: By the same token, why does Notepad allow you to create a plain text file with an `.abc` extension, why does your file archiver of choice allow you to create a ZIP file with an `.abc` extension, why will any operating system's file manager allow you to change to any file's extension to any string of characters you want, whether it accurately reflects the contents or not?  Or, better yet, why _shouldn't_ those applications allow you to do that?  That is, why should they care what extension you use?

Comment: `csc` doesn't impose any restrictions on _input_ file extensions, either..  Related: [C# compiler compiles .txt .obj .java files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813654/c-sharp-compiler-compiles-txt-obj-java-files).

Comment: Hmm,, I see it is just a _provision_ provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get what you would have got if you had asked for `Single.dll`, except with `Single.abc` as the name. You specifically asked for the compiler to do this. The compiler understood your request and did what you asked. Who knows, perhaps you chose a `.abc` extension so that it wouldn't be blocked by an e-mail client when you send it to someone else.

The compiler doesn't just give up and print an error message, because there is no reason why it should. It would require additional code to have been written for the express purpose of rejecting a case where it isn't even clear it's an error.

Comment: Thanks ,,still Is there any other real time situation which would require this?(Apart from the mail example)

Comment: @SamuelAC No situation *requires* this. If the compiler didn't support this directly, it'd be possible to work around that limitation in multiple ways, some easy, some more complicated, depending on how complete the workaround would need to be.